# Using SLD in GeoServer with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

I am facing display problem in SLD. Working on GeoServer 2.8 and OpenLayers 3.

I have one polygon layer in which I am applying SLD, when I view it in my web application polygon number is repeating each times and when I use centroid function it resolves.

But when I update SLD then that "centroid code" part vanishes from entire code.

- attached screenshot with this (repeated questions highlighted in red circle)
  [image: screenshot]
- searching on Google also

code link is: https://jsfiddle.net/5f84nwwj/

**Update**:updating SLD using Geoexplorer

please check the screenshot

[image]

Comment: How are you doing the update?

Comment: updating new features as required

Comment: how exactly are you updating the SLD file? are you using the GUI or REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this option using VendorOption

```
<sld:VendorOption name="polygonAlign">mbr</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0.3</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="partials">true</sld:VendorOption> -->

        <sld:VendorOption name="autoWrap">80</sld:VendorOption>
       <sld:VendorOption name="spaceAround">10</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">100</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="polygonAlign">ortho</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0.3</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="partials">true</sld:VendorOption>
        <sld:VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</sld:VendorOption>
```

[image]

after applying sld to layer, then problem is solved.